# Read ASB Scheduled Message ahead of time

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

Is it possible to receive scheduled messages ahead of time using the `ServiceBusClient`? Irrespective of the time they were queued for I would like to read the messages in now and handle them immediately. There is a method for reading deferred `ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync` messages but not scheduled ones. Is there a work around for this?

I am aware that `ReceiveMessageAsync` can take a max wait time so i could just leave it running but in this scenario I need the messages as fast as I can process them immediately.

```cs
var asbReceiver = new ServiceBusClient(namespaceConnectionString).CreateReceiver(queueName);

var messages = await asbReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
```

It does seem to be possible to read from the dead letter queue directly by appending doing the following when creating the Receiver but there is no equivalent SubQueue for scheduled.

```cs
new ServiceBusClient(namespaceConnectionString).CreateReceiver(queueName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions { SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter });
```

---

We are using version 7.1.2 of the azure.messaging.servicebus nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

> It does seem to be possible to read from the dead letter queue directly by appending doing the following when creating the Receiver but there is no equivalent SubQueue for scheduled.

Scheduled messages are not stored in a separate sub-queue. At least that's not publicly exposed as with dead-lettered messages and dead-letter queues.

Scheduled messages can be cancelled using the sequence number assigned during scheduling.
When a message is scheduled, it's done in the context of "schedule and forget". When a scheduled message arrives and is no longer valid, it should be discarded/ignored.